# How to apply font size while rendering HTML code in Android or Java

Tags: java, android

My code is as follows.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("6<sup>4</sup>"));
```

The output is:

[image]

Now I want to change the size of 4, so I applied the font as follows, but font is not getting applied.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("6<sup><font size="-2">4</font></sup>"));
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: font is largely deprecated, i think, you may try <div style="text-size: smaller"> or something

Comment: I had this problem. I ended up creating a different `TextView` just to conform with using `android:textSize`. However, I remember that `<font>` tag worked well. Try `<font size=\"5\"><sup>4</sup></font>`

Comment: @njzk and Sherif thanks for your reply guys but both techniques are not working. :(

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to *[android.text.Html](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java)* (on GrepCode), you may use `<small>` for smaller text, as `<font>` only supports color and face attributes.

Comment: <small> restrict to a specific size...is there any way to change size for <sup> attribute value.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution of how to set different size in a single TextView.

At first define a TextView and connect it to xml and follow this.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                android:textSize="15sp" //define the size as per your requirement 
                android:textColor="#F2F2F2" />
```

Then go to Java page

```
  TextView  txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<big><b>Xyzd</b></big><small>.com</small>"));
```

However, the big tag automatically increases 2-4 sp size and the small tag reduces 2-4 sp.

Increase and decrease your text size from xml `android:textSize="15sp"`.

It works just check it.