# Html font size not working in android application

Tags: android-layout, font-size, android-button

I am new to android, and I am developing small android application.In my application one button is there which contains text with multiple lines and with different style of text. I did it in following ways :

```
<Button
           android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
       android:layout_width="200px"
       android:layout_height="65px"  
           android:background="@drawable/download_button"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      />
```

And for displaying text I did following thing:

```
Button download_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
    String download_styledText = "<font size='10'color='white'>"
            + "Download" + "</font> " + "<br />"+""+"<font size='7'color='#883e33'>" 
            + "Save it now!"+"</font>";
    download_button.setText(Html.fromHtml(download_styledText));
```

everything is working fine the only thing is that My font size property is not working... If I define tags like big or small its working fine but for font size its not giving proper output ... What to do ? Need help ... Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

as answered here: [How to apply font size while rendering HTML code in Android or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739775/how-to-apply-font-size-while-rendering-html-code-in-android-or-java)

the font tag as implemented in android does not support size. CSS is not supported in any way either.