# HTML font size not working in the browser on android

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556741/html-font-size-not-working-in-android-application), but my goal is to simply view an HTML page correctly in a web browser on Android. Simply put, the .html file contains the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>a {font-size:25px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Some text</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to view this file on my phone with the large font size that is set in style. But every browser I have tried changes the font size to normal when loading. I know about the "accessibility" setting, but that doesn't meet my needs as it changes the font size for every page, and is also not big enough.

I have also tried other ways to change font size, such as using `font-size` property inside `<a>` tag, `<big>` tag around the text, and the font size changes accordingly on desktop but android doesn't follow suit. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What browser do you use? i think there are some setting to force font size . do you see different font sizes on other websites?

Comment: There is no single android browser.  Are you using Chrome?  WebView?  Firefox?  Something else?

Comment: I've tried Chrome and couple of Adblock browsers so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Website elements and font are too small in mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855154/website-elements-and-font-are-too-small-in-mobiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your head tag.[Read docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>a {font-size:25px;}</style>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
<body>
 <a href="https://www.google.com/">Some text</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add in the `head` tag the following `meta` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```