# Android textview html font size tag

Tags: android, html, textview

I use `<font size ="50">` tag in android textview like this

```
resultTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size='50' color='#337744'>Text Message</font>"));
resultTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=\"50\" color='#337744'>Text Message</font>"));
```

but the problem is the color tag works but size tag doesn't work

In this blog http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

it is given that font size tag works. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: [follow the link and check my answer ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739775/how-to-apply-font-size-while-rendering-html-code-in-android-or-java/33498333#33498333)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is exact question [Using size HTML attribute in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247113/using-html-in-textview) 
. It says it ignores the size. You can use use `<small>` for smaller text and so  on.  `<font>` only supports color and face attributes. see *[android.text.Html](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java)* (on GrepCode) and 
  [How to apply font size while rendering HTML code in Android or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739775/how-to-apply-font-size-while-rendering-html-code-in-android-or-java) and [TextView with different textSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize) for more. 
Hope it helps in someway.

Answer (score 30):

If you need only different size, you can use simple `<small>` or `<big>` and you can use it more times for one char.
Example: "clasic text is ok, but `<big>`bigger `<big>`is `<big>` better`</big></big></big>`" You can use `<h1>` etc. too, but here is problem with margins.

Comment: right I'm facing margin issue it consumes whole width

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one,Its working for me,use small,big key words**

```
TextView mBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#cc0029>" + "<b>"
            + "Hiiiiiiiiii" + "</b>" + "<br />" + "<small>" + "description"
            + "</small>" + "<br />" + "<small>" + "DateAdded" + "</small>"));
```