# Html Content with rgb color not displaying in android but in ios(apple) work perfectly

Tags: android, html, ios, kotlin, textview

**This is work perfect**

```
val htmlContent = "<p><span style=\"background-color: #008080;\">Heloo This is new <span style=\"color: #0000ff;\">document</span>&nbsp; <span style=\"background-color: #ffffff;\">&nbsp;TEXTT HHHH<strong>Hhhhhhhh</strong>hhhhhhhhhhhhh</span></span></p>\n" +
                            "<h1><span style=\"background-color: #008080;\"><span style=\"background-color: #ffffff;\">TEst dfsdf&nbsp;</span></span></h1>"
```

**But When I trying to set this below Html content not working in android but in ios work perfectly**

```
<p style="text-align:left;"></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span style="color: rgb(250,197,28);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: Open Sans;"><strong>Yellow </strong></span><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: Open Sans;"><strong>Ipsum</strong></span> <span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 24px;font-family: Open Sans;">is simply </span><span style="color: rgb(209,72,65);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 24px;font-family: Open Sans;">Red</span><span style="color: rgb(209,72,65);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: Open Sans;"> </span><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: Open Sans;">text </span><span style="color: rgb(65,168,95);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: Open Sans;">greenthe </span><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: Open Sans;">printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
<p style="text-align:left;"><br>&nbsp;</p>
```

**Kotlin code**

```
descriptionTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(
                    htmlContent, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should know all of HTML tags and attributes are not supported by android TextView and there are some limitations. For more information please look at the following questions:

1. [Which HTML tags are supported by Android TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754076/which-html-tags-are-supported-by-android-textview)

2. [Android textview html font size tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295881/android-textview-html-font-size-tag)

In your case, the following attributes are not supported:

1. text-align

2. font-size

3. font-family

 and also if need to set color, `rgb(int, int, int)` value is unsupported as well. 

**Solution:**

1. `text-align` attribute only supports `start`, `end` and `center` values. 

2. You can use `<small>`  tag for smaller font size or `<big>` tag for bigger font size.

3. You can use `<font>` tag and `face` attribute to set font face.

4. Use hex color code (For example #FF0000) instenad of rgb color code (For example rgb(255, 0, 0))

**Important:** If you have more than one attribute in an html tag, seperate them with `;[Space]` instead of `;`. Look at the following examples:

This exmaple doesn't work

```html
<span style="color: #ff0000;background-color: #ffffff;">
    RED
</span>
```

but this one works

```html
<span style="color: #ff0000; background-color: #ffffff;">
    RED
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android does not support all the HTML Tags.**

It Depends on the HTML version in the Android device.
For Batter output, you can use the web-view to get the desired output

You can refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/@imstudio/android-best-practice-for-text-on-android-part-3-html-tags-826ad4a0b0fe) so you will get an idea which tags supported by Android

Answer (score 0):

You can try in WebView to load that html text

```
 val encodedHtml: String = Base64.encodeToString(htmlContent.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_PADDING)
 descriptionWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

Comment: In webView Work perfect,  but I don't wont to use webView because after 120 char I have to add "Read more" label so