# How to Preserve font size using Html.toHtml and restore it using Html.fromHtml?

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, spannablestringbuilder

I am obviously very new to Android. Can anyone help me? I have EditText in which there is a functionality to set the color(different color for text) , fontsize(different font size for text), font family. That I have implemented using SpannableStringBuilder like

```
 String st = getResources().getString(R.string.default_texteditor_text);
 SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder(st);

 text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(lastTextColor), 0, st.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(lastTextSize*2), 0, st.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        editText.setText(text);
        editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and saved the editText by using

```
 String spannableString = Html.toHtml(editText.getText());
```

and at particular condition I want to retrieve the editText as it is as it was before saving it to string , so did it by

```
   Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(textPropertiesOld.getSpannableString());

    editText.setText(s);
    editText.setSelection(editText.getSelectionEnd());
```

Everything sets as it is but the font size of all the text is set similar.
Example : what I have set in edittext is

[image]

But I am getting after restoring is

[image]

When I try to print string

> Log.d("HTML = ",spannableString);

I got following HTML ....

```
<p dir="ltr"><font color ="#000000">j</font><font color
="#000000">h</font><font color ="#000000">g</font><font color ="#000000">j</font><font color ="#000000">h</font><font color ="#000000">Your Text Here...</font><br>
    <font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">Q</font></font><br>
    <font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="27">T</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="27">e</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="27">z</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="27">t</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">h</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">h</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">j</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">g</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">g</font></font><font color ="#e91d1d"><font size ="11">b</font></font></p>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you write some locat for print `st`,  `spannableString` and `s` then post it in your question?

Comment: The reason is the `font` tag implemented in Android does not support size. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739775/how-to-apply-font-size-while-rendering-html-code-in-android-or-java

Comment: why you need `spannableString` while you can set new edittext text = old `SpannableStringBuilder text` ?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh , Actually scenario is that , I am storing edittext as image(bitmap)/sticker view and double tapping on the image , we can edit this text(reset size , color) , and there can be many images of text so i have managed it using textProperties model